# Как "правильно" проектировать базы данных на Android?

Tags: android, java, sqlite, sql

**Дано:**

Новостной сайт с >400 категорий типа "политика", "экономика" etc. В каждой категории много статей.

**Задача:**

Хранить информацию о **url** категорий и их статей с множеством другой о них инфы в SQLite DB.

**Возможное решение:**

1. Создать таблицу, в коей будет храниться инфа о всех категориях (url, title, время_последнего_обновления).
2. Создать >400 таблиц с названием ***title***, где хранить инфу о статьях категории (url, title, текст_статьи, ещё_что_то).

**Вопрос:**

Верный ли это подход с точки зрения архитектуры, удобства использования, производительности etc?

**P.S.** Работать с SQLite только сегодня начал, не охота учиться неверным подходам с кучей архитектурных проблем в дальнейшем.

**UPD**

Кол-во комментов ограничено, дополняю вопрос.

[[@Yura Ivanov](/users/6117/yura-ivanov)](/users/6117/yura-ivanov) в одном из комментов верно отметил, что сложно задать не бессмысленный вопрос почти полностью не разбираясь в предмете обсуждения. Так же как и оценить верность ответов на него. Тем более, что, как верно было отмечено, вернее всего мою задачу, коя поменялась в ходе уточнения и обсуждения в комментах к ответу [[[[[[@Suvitruf](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf), решает коммент [[[[[[@Get](/users/23547/get)](/users/23547/get)](/users/23547/get)](/users/23547/get)](/users/23547/get)](/users/23547/get).

С другой стороны, ответ [[[[[[@Suvitruf](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf), насколько я понял, вполне отвечает на изначальный вопрос, коий означен выше, за что и был мною принят. Можно было бы преобразовать руками ветку комментов под ответом [[[[[[@Suvitruf](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf) в отдельный вопрос и попросить [[[[[[@Get](/users/23547/get)](/users/23547/get)](/users/23547/get)](/users/23547/get)](/users/23547/get)](/users/23547/get) там ответить и его ответ принять. Мне показалось это излишним и я ограничился награждением [[[[[[@Get](/users/23547/get)](/users/23547/get)](/users/23547/get)](/users/23547/get)](/users/23547/get)](/users/23547/get) очками.

По поводу подхода к решению вопросов я бы поспорил, но площадка эта не этой цели создавалась. Скажу лишь, что согласен с тем, что гораздо эффективнее, в долгосрочной перспективе, читать книги/получить профильное образование etc, с другой стороны, считаю, при нужде в немедленном результате практика задавания вопросов на форуме для вопросов имеет право на существование. Тем более, что я стараюсь участвовать в жизни сообщества, помогать другим людям и ожидаю соответствующей помощи взамен.

По поводу

> Программирование - это не снипеты из интернета склеивать. Вы сэкономили кучу времени ничего не узнав

я бы тоже поспорил. По крайней мере по пункту "ничего не узнав". Я узнал, как минимум как можно решать типовые задачи, избежать глупых ошибок и пару терминов.

Comment: Ужасно. Почитайте про базы данных что-нибудь. Нельзя такие вопросы задавать.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, про базы данных немного читал в учебнике по Андроид. Но там были только базовые примеры, совсем непохожие на стоящую предо мною задачу.
Вместо без тезисной критики лучше скажите, что конкретно ужасно в моём вопросе. И разве не для вопросов (пусть ужасных, хотя на фоне многого на форуме, мой, как мне кажется, не так уж и ужасен) создан форум? Вопросов людей которые зачастую не могут даже правильно сформулировать запрос в гугл, т.к. не знают что конкретно спросить?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я посмотрел две серии доктора Хауса, скажите, я вот балгаркой трепанацию собрался делать, неохота учиться...  
Ну серьезно. Ваш вопрос не должен возникать, если вы погружаетесь в новую для вас область. Сначала нужно что-то узнать, где-то что-то прочитать чуть больше пары строк в андроид-учебнике. Там про бд написано для тех, кто знает про них или на будущее: возьмет что-нибудь почитать.  
Ответ про внешний ключ, поверьте, и про "перекрестную таблицу" вам ничем не помогут и не уберегут от кучи архитектурных проблем в дальнейшем.  
Комментарий ваш чуть ниже об этом и говорит...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, позволю себе усомниться в уместности приведённой вами аналогии. Вижу ситуацию, скорее, в ключе "не смотрел Хауса, но очень надо перевязать порез на пальце, уж очень клаву пачкает. Подскажите подойдёт ли такой узел (ссылка на пикчу с морским узлом)".
И да, я мог бы взять полноценный учебник по СУБД и читать его с неделю. Всё понять и вопрос не задавать. Но в данный момент мне нужно просто упорядочить хранение данных в приложении. Я знаю, что SQL лучше, чем то, что я пользую сейчас. Единственно, что мне мешало, решено этим вопросом. Я сэкономил кучу времени.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, удачи вам с "внешним ключом", не болейте.

Comment: никогда не читайте про базы данных из учебников про андроид. читайте про базы данных из учебников про базы данных. "создать >400 таблиц" - это ппц.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, мне чудится сарказм в ваших словах. ) Если это так, то не могли бы вы лучше разъяснить, чем этот подход плох или хотя бы кинуть ссылку на книгу хорошую по вопросу? По моему опыту, простое гугление плохо помогает, т.к. благодаря ему и устаревшей инфе я написал приложение, кое сейчас полностью переделываю. )

Comment: @argamidon, спорить не буду, вы правы. Но мне показалось, что достаточно имеющихся навыков и этого вопроса, чтобы реализовать в приложении ту фичу, коя мне нужна. И я всегда считал, что лучше задать глупый вопрос, чем, не задавая его, сделать глупость.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, причем тут сарказм. тут сожаление о том как вы подходите к вопросу. Это, конечно, ваше дело, но задав этот не глупый, а бессмысленный вопрос, вы не можете оценить предлагаемые вам решения объективно. Т.е. вы не знаете правильно вам советуют или бред какой-то. Вот вы приняли ответ про две таблицы и внешний ключ, в итоге у вас задача чудным образом преобразилась в другую и реально правильный ответ написан в комментарии @Get.  
Программирование - это не снипеты из интернета склеивать. Вы сэкономили кучу времени ничего не узнав, поздравляю [тут сарказм, да]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 таблицы:

1) Таблица категорий ( >400 записей).

2) Таблица новостей, в которой есть внешний ключ на таблицу категорий.

> Работать с SQLite только сегодня начал, не охота учиться неверным подходам с кучей архитектурных проблем в дальнейшем.

Подобное вещи при проектировании почти не зависят от выбранной СУБД (если мы говорим именно про реляционные).

Comment: Т.е. вы предлагаете складывать все новости в одну таблицу, в коей будет колонка, содержащая инфу из первой таблицы по ключу-категории?

Меня несколько смущает возможное разрастание 2-ой таблицы до громадных объёмов и производительность выборки по тысячам записей...

Чем этот вариант лучше, на ваш взгляд, чем создание по таблице на каждую категорию?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб и при появлении новой категории будете новую таблицу создавать? Ваш подход все рекомендации ломает. Btw, СУБД будет спокойно работать и при миллионе записей в одной таблице )

Comment: Почитал тут https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Внешний_ключ про внешние ключи. Из приведённого примера, как я понял, следует, что запись во второй таблице сможет ссылаться только на одну запись из 1-ой таблицы.

Всё не влезло, см. след. коммент.

Comment: В моём случае у каждой новости может быть от 0 до n категорий. Как действовать в данном случае? Дублировать записи во второй таблице с разными внешними ключами (как в примере по ссылке) или создавать во 2-ой таблице n (где n = неизвестное кол-во возможных категорий новости <=колв-ву категорий (>400)) колонок с возможным **NULL** значением, кои будут содержать внешний ключ на n записей первой таблицы?
Заранее спасибо за ответ на многобуквенный коммент)

Comment: Создать перекрестную таблицу с указанием поля с ид категории и поля с ид новости. В ней будет самое большое количество записей, но поскольку все записи будут цифровые и, возможно, проиндексированные, таблица будет занимать не очень много места и быстро работать.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял:

1. Нужна 3-я таблица, коя будет содержать 3 колонки (_id, id_of_article, id_of_category).
2. Во 2-й колонке будет столько полей каждой новости, сколько у неё есть категорий.
3. В 3-й колонке будут id категорий, к коим относится новость.
4. Так можно будет выбирать из 1-й таблицы категорию по title/url и по её id получать все новости категории.
5. Также можно будет получить все категории конкретной новости по id новости
.
6. Всё это будет немного весить и быстро работать, т.к. в 3-й таблице будут только **integer** значения.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб сначала опишите модель данных, с которой удобно работать, а потому можно будет перенести эту модель в БД, где каждая сущность из вашей модели будет отдельная таблица. 
А чтобы не мучиться, воспользуйтесь ORMLite или любой другой ORM.

Answer (score 2):

Основа правильного проектирования базы данных - структура БД должна быть статична , то есть "прирастать" записями в таблицы, а не самими таблицами . В общем то , если в процессе работы спроектированной вами структуры БД понадобилась новая таблица , то вы спроектировали свою БД неверно и надо все переделывать.

Для организации данных в БД используется механизм связывания , который имеет три типа связей:

1. Один к одному.
2. Один ко многим.
3. Многие ко многим.

Данные связи перекрывают все возможные варианты хранения данных любой структуры сложности и обеспечивают всестороннюю обработку этих данных - выборку нужных значений по всевозможным критериям , добавление записей , изменение и удаление их средствами БД , предназначенными для этого , а не генерацией скриптов по созданию новых таблиц , их удаления и прочие такие ужасы.

Приводить конкретные примеры реализации связей я здесь не буду , так как это довольно объемный текст , к тому же отлично освещен на всевозможных ресурсах .

В качестве первой книги по проектированию БД хотел бы настоятельно рекомендовать :

`Линн Бейли - Изучаем SQL (Бестселлеры O'Reilly) - 2012`

Книга научит вас проектировать базы данных , понять организацию связей в БД и использовать язык SQL для эффективной обработки данных , хранящихся в вашей БД . Написана живым языком , полна простых и понятных примеров , очень подробна в основах организации БД и вообще просто находка начинающему . Обычно книги по СУБД скучны , непонятны и унылы , что не добавляет рабости обучения , но это совсем не такая , прочитав ее вы наконец поймете , как это делается .

Answer (score 0):

Я не очень понял, о каком Android идет речь. Если о мобильных устройствах, то мне не ясно, зачем на них грузить всю базу целиком. Предложенный [[@Suvitruf](/users/15479/suvitruf)](/users/15479/suvitruf) вариант верен и удобен для дальнейшего расширения или сужения БД, а также для частичного заполнения данными.

Comment: 1. Я пишу (переписываю с нуля уже готовое) Android-приложение клиент новостного сайта.
2. Всю базу целиком желаю встроить для ускорения подгрузки статей в списках при скролле вниз. Если я правильно понял, то таблица с ~ 10 000 записей с ~10 колонками, содержащими значения типа url, title, date, category, author, image_url etc, не должна весить слишком много, зато значительно снизит потребление трафика при парсинге сайта и обеспечит офлайн-доступ хотя бы к заголовкам новостей, вышедших за пару последних дней.

Comment: А как вариант, научить сайт отдавать JSON?

Comment: @Alerx, к сожалению, доступа к сайту у меня нет.