# Как можно реализовать?

Tags: android, база-данных

Доброго времени суток,

Я пытаюсь создать приложение на андроид "расписание занятий" на java. 
Создал БД, таблицу "дисциплины". В ней 3 поля предмет, преподаватель, аудитория. 
Работает всё хорошо, отображается через CursorAdapter в listview.

Теперь думаю создать 6 таблиц для каждого учебного дня недели с такими же полями, как в таблице "предметы" (только с  разными названиями)  ;

На главном активити через адаптер выводить расписание для выбранного дня.(Если выбранный день == четверг, то выводить содержимое соответствующей таблицы);

- Посредством чего будет удобнее реализовать отображение расписания на текущий день? Также как и список дисциплин через Cursor Adapter? Какие ещё есть возможности?
- Есть ли более простое решение с таблицами дней недели, не создавая 6 отдельных для каждого дня?

Большое спасибо за внимание, надеюсь на ваши советы.

Comment: Приложение вы создаете на Java через фреймворк Android. Android Studio - среда разработки, говорить: "Я создаю приложение на android studio" то же самое, что "я написал письмо на красной ручке" (а не на русском языке).

Comment: По вопросу - если вы работаете с БД, то и всю информацию необходимо хранить в БД и выводить через классы, для работы с БД (`Cursor`, `CursorAdapter`, `CursorLoader` и тд)? какие тут еще могут быть варианты. Правильная организация базы данных - отдельная дисциплина (СУБД), которая включает тысячи страниц нужных знаний. Начать приобщаться можно с [этого ответа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/419255/177345) и книги, которая там указана.

Comment: @pavlofff, Исправил. Насчёт работы с БД это более менее понятно. Меня больше интересует куда вывод сделать, в какой компонент.

Comment: во первых, если у вас уже есть таблица Предметы, то не надо создавать другую таблицу, куда включены эти предметы, записывая ту же информацию повторно, следует использовать связь "один ко многим" и в таблицах дней недели указывать только ID предметов из таблицы Предметы. Если количество предметов в каждый день разное, то в виджет на основе адаптера отображать логичнее всего - `GridView` или `ListView`(`RecyclerView`)

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь я пошёл читать и пробовать)

Comment: Думаю было бы лучше сделать одну таблицу: День недели, ID предмета, прочая информация. Правда не совсем ясно что вы будете делать, когда хотят заранее ввести изменения в расписании, например со следующей недели предмет переезжает в другую аудиторию. Но на этой неделе надо показывать еще в старой аудитории. Напрашивается интервал дат действия данной записи расписания, что бы можно было создать запись с января по март, а при изменениях создать другую с апреля

Comment: @Mike Если сделать одну таблицу, как расписание будет выводиться? К примеру, у 5-и предметов указан в графе день недели "Вторник", они вразнобой появятся во вторник? А насчёт изменений в расписании, к этому вернусь, когда закончу хотя бы основу приложения, и получу сырую рабочую версию)

Comment: А как бы вы сделали если бы вторник был в отдельной таблице ? Если база SQL то в любом случае необходимо использовать некий order by, потому как порядок записей в таблице не  гарантирован. Думаю поле с временем нужно, что бы правильно отсортировать. Вот и в одной таблице точно так же. отбираете записи за вторник и сортируете по времени

Comment: Я просто хотел сделать номер занятия вместо времени, где 1 = "08:30-09:20", 2="09:35-10:25". Выводиться будет время, а не просто число. Так проще, кажется)